# Changing Android application language in Kotlin at runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, translation

I've been recently wondering, how can I change application language at a runtime. I found a lot of code in Java, but I'm not familiar with it at all, and even knowing that Kotlin is built on java, I couldn't rewrite it at my own.

Right now I have this snippet:

```
fun setLocale(languageCode: String) {
    Log.d("important", "Accessed with: $languageCode")
    val locale = Locale("en")
    val configuration = resources.configuration
    configuration.setLocale(locale)
    val context = requireContext().createConfigurationContext(configuration)
    requireActivity().applicationContext.resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, requireActivity().resources.displayMetrics)
    requireActivity().recreate()
}
```

Which works, but when `.recreate()` is called, my application blacks out for around 5 seconds and only then updates the language. How can I skip this blackout and update the text when it's ready to be updated? I want to update whole application language, so I'm using application context. The `setLocale()` method is located inside the **Fragment** class, so you can use any methods accessible in it.

Note:
My strings.xml files are configured correctly, language changes, so it's not a problem

Comment: Sounds like you may be calling some blocking code in your `onCreate()` function. Can you share your code from that? Or maybe you're running on an emulator and it's just running really slowly.

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/p25KCP1t

Comment: AppSettingsManager.loadData(key) is basically like sharedPreferences.getString(key, "")

Comment: That all looks fine to me. I don't know what else could cause your issue, but I don't personally use `recreate()`. Maybe someone else will know, but my best guess is slow emulation. Try on a real device.